# use ExoPlayer in React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, exoplayer

Hi I'm using react native, so I needed exoplayer to show subtitle on it in android....
I added exoplayer inside my app, after that should I do something to use exoplayer as default or it will link to react-native-video ?
thanks

Comment: As I imagen after adding ExoPlayer, when you use react-native-video it should use ExoPlayer as default but how could I be sure am I doing right ? cause my codes aren't working ...

Answer (score 5):

According to the [react native video ExoPlayer documentation](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/tree/master/android-exoplayer), there are some ExoPlayer only props. Use one of them in your app and check if they're being called or not.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the path of the project like this.

```
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
// Add below this line ↑
include ':react-native-video'  // -> you must add this line on new version
project(':react-native-video').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-video/android-exoplayer')
include ':app'
```

look [here](https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video/issues/1747#issuecomment-531736338) for more details

It will start to use android-exoplayer

I'v also added

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

in `AndroidManifest.xml` to make it work in release builds as well.

If it doesn't help, please add

```
import com.brentvatne.react.ReactVideoPackage;
...


@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
   List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();

   packages.add(new ReactVideoPackage()); // <<< This line

   return packages;
}
```

to `MainApplication.java`

Answer (score 2):

As of now **ExoPlayer** is not autolinked with `react-native-video`. To link it with your project and use it, create a file named react-native.config.js in your project root. Then add the following code in the file:

```
module.exports = {
  dependencies: {
    'react-native-video': {
      platforms: {
        android: {
          sourceDir: '../node_modules/react-native-video/android-exoplayer'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: It seems not working on latest versions.
It emits error `The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.` while build

Comment: You saved me hours of researching, thank you

Comment: @Imran app is crashing on adding the above line code. Is there something else to add in it

Answer (score 1):

For those who have encountered this question in 2024, it's worth noting that as of version 6.x.x (alpha or beta), react-native-video has adopted ExoPlayer as its default implementation for android.

There is no need to enable it via any config.

Source: https://react-native-video.github.io/react-native-video/updating#android

Answer (score 0):

two way we can do

first way

```
   module.exports = {
  project: {
    ios: {},
    android: {},
  },
  assets: ['./src/assets/fonts'],
  dependencies: {
    'react-native-video': {
      platforms: {
        android: {
          sourceDir: '../node_modules/react-native-video/android-exoplayer',
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Second way

You can assign custom project directory for react-native-video in android/settings.gradle after automatic linking like so:

```
rootProject.name = 'MyAwesomeRNApp'
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
project(':react-native-video').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-video/android-exoplayer')
include ':app'
```

And Last do not forgot ,node_modules/react-native-video/android-exoplayer/build.gradle

set 2.13.3 version

```
   implementation('com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.13.3') {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support'
        }

  implementation('com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-okhttp:2.13.3') {
        exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', module: 'okhttp'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

expo-av uses exoplayer, you can install this package (depends on expo though)